# How to get distinct rows of a matrix in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a big matrix and MATLAB R2012b. I like to get distinct rows of the matrix with their frequencies. How to do it?

In addition let us think two rows with same entries are equal i.e. $(0 , 0 , 1)$ and $(0 , 1 , 0)$ are equivalent. Then how to get number of distinct rows and their frequencies?

I was trying with the function **sortrows()**. But it is not very efficient. Also I do not want them to count manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define an example matrix:

```
A = [ 0 1 0;
      1 0 0;
      0 1 0;
      1 1 1];
```

1. If **rows with a different order should be considered as distinct**: use [`unique(...,'rows')`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get unique row labels, and  [`histc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) to do the counting:

   ```
   [~, jj, kk] = unique(A,'rows');
   unique_rows = A(jj,:);
   count = histc(kk, unique(kk));
   ```

   The `jj` ouput of `unique` contains the indices of unique rows of `A`. The `kk` output is a label that tells, for each row of `A`, which of the unique rows given  by `jj` it equals. In other words, `A(jj(kk),:)` reproduces `A` (but using only the set of unique rows given by `jj`).

   The code gives

   ```
   unique_rows =
        0     1     0
        1     0     0
        1     1     1

   count =
        2
        1
        1
   ```
2. If **rows should be considered equal even if they are in a different order**: just sort each row before calling `unique(...,'rows')`:

   ```
   [~, jj, kk] = unique(sort(A,2),'rows');
   unique_rows = A(jj,:);
   count = histc(kk, unique(kk));
   ```

   This gives

   ```
   unique_rows =
        0     1     0
        1     1     1

   count =
        3
        1
   ```

Comment: I am not getting some steps. What is the role of kk and jj and how are you counting. Can you elaborate this answer please?

Comment: `jj` is an index vector and gives you the row number of the unique rows, `kk` tells you which rows are equal. Yes, I agree. I might to good to elaborate on that. +1 anyway...

Comment: @Dutta Using the second and third ouputs of `unique` is tricky at the beginning, but it's very useful once you master it. I've added an explanation. I hope it's more easily understood now

Comment: @kkuilla Thanks. Yes, an explanation was in order. I've added one